# Create with pipe a user defined filename batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, pipe

I want to read from stdin a filename for a batch file that I need to create. All in a single line and using pipe.
When I try the cmd is creating the .bat before I put in the name.

```
set /p filename= | copy NUL %a%.bat
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not how the pipe works. The pipe takes the output of the previous command, and makes it the input of the next command. Your `set /p filename=` command doesn't produce any output, so the `copy NUL %a%.bat` doesn't get any input, but that's irrelevant anyway, because the `copy` command doesn't take any input anyway. Your `copy NUL %a%.bat` command creates an empty file called .bat because you haven't defined a variable called `a`, and so `%a%` gets expanded to the empty string.

What you want to do requires two commands:

```
set /p filename=
copy NUL %filename%.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Klitos Kyriacou's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35260981/45375):

A pipe is definitely not the right choice, but `&` and `&&` can *in principle* be used to execute multiple commands on a *single line*, so you may be *tempted* to do the following:

```
:: !! WRONG
set /p filename="" && copy NUL "%filename%.bat"
```

The problem is that variable reference `%filename%` is expanded *before* execution of the command line begins.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, if you turn on *delayed expansion* (via `cmd /V`, or, inside a batch file with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (which also makes all variables local)), you *can* make this work, assuming you use `!...!` to reference your variables:

```
:: OK, assuming delayed expansion is on.
set /p filename="" && copy NUL "!filename!.bat"
```

---

<sup>[1] [Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262347/45375) works around that problem with a *trick*: `call` effectively delays expansion, but that requires that `%filename%` *not* be expanded up front, which is why the `%%` are doubled to result in *literal* `%` chars.: `%%filename%%` is *initially* expanded to *literal* `%filename%`, which is *then* interpreted by `call` as a variable reference - by which time the variable already has its value.

Since `%` chars. cannot be escaped on the *command line*, a different approach is needed: `%filename^%` achieves the same as above.</sup>

Comment: Also, note that the use of `#` as a comment is a different language. CMD will be very confused if you try using it, but then again i keep finding myself using `//` in batch files..

Answer (score 2):

As a line in a batch file, use

```
SET /p "filename=Filename ? "&CALL COPY NUL %%filename%% >nul
```

If you are entering this at the prompt, reduce `%%` to `%`

Note that the `>nul` suppresses the `file copied` message.

Comment: A neat trick, but at the prompt you should use `%filename^%`, not just `%filename%`, otherwise, if `%filename%` already happens to have a value before the command executes, _that_ value will be used.